# Using CREATE VIEW with multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use the CREATE VIEW along with multiple cells from 3 different tables with multiplication between two cells. There is a syntax error somewhere with this somewhere but I can't seem to identify it.

```
CREATE VIEW ORDERS AS CustFirstname, CustLastName, o.Ordernumber AS OrderNumber, 
o. OrderDate AS OrderDate, o.ShipDate AS ShipDate, c.QuotedPrice, 
c.QuantityOrdered, c.QuotedPrice * c.QuantityOrdered AS ItemTotal FROM Customers 
NATURAL JOIN Orders o NATURAL JOIN Order_Details c
```

The output i'm trying to get is 
|CustFirstname|CustLastName|OrderNumber|OrderDate|ShipDate|ItemTotal|

**Update: If I replace "CREATE VIEW ORDERS AS" with "SELECT" it seems to work**

Comment: `CREATE VIEW ORDERS AS SELECT CustFirstname, ...` is working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your `CREATE VIEW` statement you are missing the `SELECT` of the query:

```
CREATE VIEW ORDERS AS 
    SELECT CustFirstname, CustLastName, o.Ordernumber AS OrderNumber, 
        o. OrderDate AS OrderDate, o.ShipDate AS ShipDate, c.QuotedPrice, 
        c.QuantityOrdered, c.QuotedPrice * c.QuantityOrdered AS ItemTotal 
    FROM Customers NATURAL JOIN Orders o NATURAL JOIN Order_Details c
```

On the definition of `CREATE VIEW` you can see a `select_statement` is required:

```
CREATE
    [OR REPLACE]
    [ALGORITHM = {UNDEFINED | MERGE | TEMPTABLE}]
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    [SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }]
    VIEW view_name [(column_list)]
    AS select_statement
    [WITH [CASCADED | LOCAL] CHECK OPTION]
```

> You can find more information about `CREATE VIEW` on the [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html).

Comment: Thanks. My understanding was wrong as I thought select was not required when using create view

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the most important statement which is "SELECT".

```
CREATE VIEW ORDERS AS 
SELECT CustFirstname, CustLastName, o.Ordernumber AS OrderNumber, 
o. OrderDate AS OrderDate, o.ShipDate AS ShipDate, c.QuotedPrice, 
c.QuantityOrdered, c.QuotedPrice * c.QuantityOrdered AS ItemTotal FROM Customers 
NATURAL JOIN Orders o NATURAL JOIN Order_Details c
```

Comment: Thanks for the help